# Processing multidimensional array in php and send to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have mysql table with fields:

```
id | building | title | parent
```

And I want to create timeline calendar through fullcalendar.io.

I need to create this:

```
{ id: '1', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
   { id: '2', title: 'Room D1' },
    { id: '3', title: 'Room D2' }
 ] }, etc...
```

I did this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'id'       => $row['id'],
        'building' => $row['building'],
        'title'    => $row['title']
    );
}
```

How can I add to this array element "children" in which all element will be collacted with same 'parent'? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `id` as key of the array, and use it to store children values inside the parent element:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $id = $row['id'] ;
    $id_parent = $row['parent'] ;

    if ($id_parent)
    {
        $data[$id_parent]['children'][] = array(
            'id'       => $id,
            'title'    => $row['fname']
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $data[$id] = array(
            'id'       => $id,
            'building' => $row['building'],
            'title'    => $row['fname']
        );
    }
}

// reset indices :
$data = array_values($data);

// create the JSON:
echo json_encode($data);
```